# Calculate hourly intervals from start/end timestamp in R

Tags: r, time

I've tried looking around, but I haven't found a similar question. Any help pointing in the right direction is welcomed. I'm working with electric car charging data. Below is a reproducible example. The timestamps indicate when the associated charger is occupied by a driver.

```
charger_id <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)
start_time <- as_datetime(c("2019-06-13 10:56:36", "2019-06-13 15:56:36", "2019-06-13 17:55:56", "2019-06-13 08:55:27", "2019-06-13 04:25:56", "2019-06-13 12:45:47")) 
end_time <- as_datetime(c("2019-06-13 14:08:10", "2019-06-14 10:15:46", "2019-06-13 23:20:31", "2019-06-13 17:50:51", "2019-06-13 09:20:16", "2019-06-13 19:20:06"))
status <- c("charging", "charging", "charging", "charging", "charging", "charging")
df <-  data.frame("charger_id" = charger_id, "start_time" = start_time, "end_time" = end_time, "status" = status)
```

**WHAT I HAVE CURRENTLY:**

```
charger_id |      start_time     |      end_time       |    status     |
     1     | 2019-06-13 10:56:36 | 2019-06-13 14:08:10 |   charging    |
     1     | 2019-06-13 15:16:26 | 2019-06-14 10:15:46 |   charging    |
     2     | 2019-06-13 17:55:56 | 2019-06-13 24:20:31 |   charging    |
     3     | 2019-06-13 08:55:27 | 2019-06-13 17:50:51 |   charging    |
     4     | 2019-06-13 04:25:56 | 2019-06-13 09:20:16 |   charging    |
     4     | 2019-06-13 12:45:47 | 2019-06-13 19:20:06 |   charging    |
```

And I want to calculate, for each session, the hourly use.

For example, regarding `charger_id = 1`, its first session took place between `10:56:36` and `14:08:10`, so that's 192 minutes spread out over 5 hours. The resulting table for this session should look something like this.

**WHAT I WANT:**

```
charger_id |         hour        |    time_occupied    |
    ...    |         ...         |          ...        |
     1     | 2019-06-13 08:00:00 |           0         |
     1     | 2019-06-13 09:00:00 |           0         |
     1     | 2019-06-13 10:00:00 |           4         |
     1     | 2019-06-13 11:00:00 |           60        |
     1     | 2019-06-13 12:00:00 |           60        |
     1     | 2019-06-13 13:00:00 |           60        |
     1     | 2019-06-13 14:00:00 |           8         |
     1     | 2019-06-13 15:00:00 |           0         |
    ...    |          ...        |          ...        |
```

The
`time_occupied`  column indicates the elapsed time (in minutes) that a specific charger, for a specific session, was occupied during a specific hour.

This table is a small snapshot of the very long final table I'm looking for. For every `charger_id` in the dataset, there would be an hourly timestamp record (eg. `2019-06-13 15:00:00` ) and a `time_occupied` column, indicating that session's hourly occupancy. Every charger in the dataset would have 24 hourly timestamps per day, 168 per week, etc..

For more clarification, this link to describes the same goal I'm looking to achieve, but was asked for SQL: https://community.oracle.com/message/13318002#13318002

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. It looks like the result you want has the same `charger_id` and `end_time`. I'm not at all clear on what the modified `start_time` means or how you calculated it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've edited my question and I hope what I'm trying to do is more clear now.

Comment: Getting clearer. Can you please specify what `use` represents or how you'd like to calculate it? I've got a few ideas, but they're contradictory so at least one of my ideas must be wrong. :)

Comment: Okay, I've tried to address your question, and explain in more detail the final table I'm looking for.  I hope this explains things better

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution. It uses `foverlaps` which means that any start time/charger id pair that has a `time_used` of 0 gets excluded. It wouldn't be too hard to add those rows back in if you want after the fact. It should also work quickly for large data sets as the `data.table` version of `foverlaps` is quite quick.

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
charger_id <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4)
start_time <- as_datetime(c("2019-06-13 10:56:36", "2019-06-13 15:56:36", "2019-06-13 17:55:56", "2019-06-13 08:55:27", "2019-06-13 04:25:56", "2019-06-13 12:45:47")) 
end_time <- as_datetime(c("2019-06-13 14:08:10", "2019-06-14 10:15:46", "2019-06-13 23:20:31", "2019-06-13 17:50:51", "2019-06-13 09:20:16", "2019-06-13 19:20:06"))
df <-  data.table("charger_id" = charger_id, "start_time" = start_time, "end_time" = end_time)
setkey(df, start_time, end_time)

start <- as_datetime('2019-06-12')
end <- as_datetime('2019-06-14')
times <- seq.POSIXt(start, end, by = 'hour')
df_times <- data.table(start = times[-length(times)], end = times[-1])
setkey(df_times, start, end)

df <- foverlaps(df, df_times, by.x = c('start_time', 'end_time'), by.y = c('start', 'end'))
df[, time_occupied := as.double(difftime(min(.SD[,c(end, end_time)]), max(.SD[,c(start, start_time)]), units = 'mins')), .(start, charger_id)]

df[order(charger_id), .(charger_id, start, time_occupied)]
#>     charger_id               start time_occupied
#>  1:          1 2019-06-13 10:00:00      3.400000
#>  2:          1 2019-06-13 11:00:00     60.000000
#>  3:          1 2019-06-13 12:00:00     60.000000
#>  4:          1 2019-06-13 13:00:00     60.000000
#>  5:          1 2019-06-13 14:00:00      8.166667
#>  6:          1 2019-06-13 15:00:00      3.400000
#>  7:          1 2019-06-13 16:00:00     60.000000
#>  8:          1 2019-06-13 17:00:00     60.000000
#>  9:          1 2019-06-13 18:00:00     60.000000
#> 10:          1 2019-06-13 19:00:00     60.000000
#> 11:          1 2019-06-13 20:00:00     60.000000
#> 12:          1 2019-06-13 21:00:00     60.000000
#> 13:          1 2019-06-13 22:00:00     60.000000
#> 14:          1 2019-06-13 23:00:00     60.000000
#> 15:          2 2019-06-13 17:00:00      4.066667
#> 16:          2 2019-06-13 18:00:00     60.000000
#> 17:          2 2019-06-13 19:00:00     60.000000
#> 18:          2 2019-06-13 20:00:00     60.000000
#> 19:          2 2019-06-13 21:00:00     60.000000
#> 20:          2 2019-06-13 22:00:00     60.000000
#> 21:          2 2019-06-13 23:00:00     20.516667
#> 22:          3 2019-06-13 08:00:00      4.550000
#> 23:          3 2019-06-13 09:00:00     60.000000
#> 24:          3 2019-06-13 10:00:00     60.000000
#> 25:          3 2019-06-13 11:00:00     60.000000
#> 26:          3 2019-06-13 12:00:00     60.000000
#> 27:          3 2019-06-13 13:00:00     60.000000
#> 28:          3 2019-06-13 14:00:00     60.000000
#> 29:          3 2019-06-13 15:00:00     60.000000
#> 30:          3 2019-06-13 16:00:00     60.000000
#> 31:          3 2019-06-13 17:00:00     50.850000
#> 32:          4 2019-06-13 04:00:00     34.066667
#> 33:          4 2019-06-13 05:00:00     60.000000
#> 34:          4 2019-06-13 06:00:00     60.000000
#> 35:          4 2019-06-13 07:00:00     60.000000
#> 36:          4 2019-06-13 08:00:00     60.000000
#> 37:          4 2019-06-13 09:00:00     20.266667
#> 38:          4 2019-06-13 12:00:00     14.216667
#> 39:          4 2019-06-13 13:00:00     60.000000
#> 40:          4 2019-06-13 14:00:00     60.000000
#> 41:          4 2019-06-13 15:00:00     60.000000
#> 42:          4 2019-06-13 16:00:00     60.000000
#> 43:          4 2019-06-13 17:00:00     60.000000
#> 44:          4 2019-06-13 18:00:00     60.000000
#> 45:          4 2019-06-13 19:00:00     20.100000
#>     charger_id               start time_occupied
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for. I was hoping if you could clarify some of the DT syntax (I'm more familiar with tidyverse).  Could you explain: 1) how you are using .SD in this operation, (what's the subset?) and 2) what does `.(start, charger_id)` do when you assign the column `time_occupied`?

Comment: Sure thing! First of all, in the `data.table` syntax, the square brackets take 3 arguments: `[i, j, by]`. The first, `i` deals mostly with subsetting rows. The second, `j` deals mostly with column selections or transformations. And finally `by` deals with groupings. Your two questions are actually tied to one another. `.(start, charger_id)` essentially means "do what i'm asking for each combination of `start` and `charger_id`)". And so when I use `.SD` in the `j` argument, I'm essentially subsetting down to a `data.table` that only has a single combination of `start` and `charger_id`.